# Change colour of font after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to change the color of "View Results" text in below ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>​
```

I've tried overriding the css 'pds-view-results' which is what "View Results" is styled with but no effect :

```
.pds-view-results {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/36/

Comment: Could you explain me?  Do you want to change the color of view Results Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the link color is already specified by a rule, you should override it via `!important` keyword

```
.pds-view-results {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from javascript :

```
$('.pds-view-results').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Why do it with JavaScript, if you can do it with pure CSS?

Comment: In order to avoid "important" that you can't override if it's yet present.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set your `style` **late**

That way you can avoid `!important` and `javascript`. But, I'll advice you to put only the last css rule like this, as it may cause flickering. Try it, it may work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

<style type='text/css'>
    .pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.pds-view-results {
    color: red;
}
#PDI_container6352993 .pds-links a{
  color:blue;
}
</style>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nXS4J/